# How to loop through an entire list and give an error if an item doesn't exist in the list

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm trying to make a program which loops through the entire list and if an object exists it executes a function and if it doesn't it gives an error.

Here is my code:

```
x = ['apple','orange','banana','kiwi']

enter = input('enter your fruit: ')

def exists():
  print('this fruit exists')

for fruit in x:
   if fruit == str(enter):
     exists()
     break
 else:
   print("this fruit doesn't exist")
```

The output I'm trying to achieve is:

```
enter your fruit: kiwi
this fruit exists
```

And if the fruit doesn't exist:

```
enter your fruit: pineapple 
this fruit doesn't exist
```

But the output I get if an fruit exists is:

```
enter your fruit: kiwi
this fruit doesn't exist
this fruit doesn't exist
this fruit doesn't exist
this fruit exists
```

And if the fruit doesn't exist:

```
enter your fruit: pineapple
this fruit doesn't exist
this fruit doesn't exist
this fruit doesn't exist
this fruit doesn't exist
```

Is there anyway to make it so it goes through the whole list and if an object exists it only outputs one time.

And if the object doesn't exist it outputs only once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to use `in` operator:

```py
x = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "kiwi"]

enter = input("enter your fruit: ")

if enter in x:
    print("this fruit exists")
else:
    print("this fruit doesn't exist")
```

---

OR: Use `for-else` statement:

```py
x = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "kiwi"]

enter = input("enter your fruit: ")

for f in x:
    if f == enter:
        print("this fruit exists")
        break
else:
    print("this fruit doesn't exist")
```

Comment: Thanks, my goal was to try and use the for loop

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
x = ['apple','orange','banana','kiwi']

enter = input('enter your fruit: ')

if enter in x:
    print('this fruit exists')
else:
   print("this fruit doesn't exist")
```

You don't need to iterate through whole list. Just check if `enter` is in that list or not should solve your problem.

Or if you want to iterate through whole list which is bad practice, you can do this:

```
x = ['apple','orange','banana','kiwi']

enter = input('enter your fruit: ')
error=0
for e in x:
    if enter in x:
        print('this fruit exists')
        break
    else:
        error=1
if error==1:
    print("this fruit doesn't exist")
```

You can try one-line(inline) solution also, technically not one line but one line, easy to do and hard to debug:

```
x = ['apple','orange','banana','kiwi']

enter = input('enter your fruit: ')
if not [print("found") for f in x if enter==f]:print("not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in here:

```
for fruit in x:
   if fruit == str(enter):
     exists()
     break
 else:
   print('this fruit doesn't exist')
```

```
x = ['apple','orange','banana','kiwi']
```

The above code iterates over `x` and checks if `enter` is equal to some fruit.

- 1st iteration: fruit = 'apple' and enter = 'kiwi'. They don't match, so print `this fruit doesn't exist`
- 2nd iteration: fruit = 'orange' and enter = 'kiwi'. They don't match, so print `this fruit doesn't exist`
- 3rd iteration: fruit = 'banana' and enter = 'kiwi'. They don't match, so print `this fruit doesn't exist`
- 4th iteration: fruit = 'kiwi' and enter = 'kiwi'. They match, so print `this fruit exists`

You just need to know if `kiwi` exists in `x` or not. For this **Use the `in` operator**

```
if enter in x:
    exists()
    break
else:
    print('this fruit doesn't exist')
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired result in your source code, you only need to align `else:` exactly with `for` (see https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html):

```
x = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'kiwi']
enter = input('enter your fruit: ')

def exists():
    print('this fruit exists')

for fruit in x:
    if fruit == enter:
        exists()
        break
else:  # else must be under for and is executed if the loop has been executed completely, without interruption (break)
    print("this fruit doesn't exist")
```

Explanation. In your source code `else:` is inaccurately aligned, and seems to be treated by the interpreter as part of the construct `if ... else`, not part of `for ... else`. Therefore, whenever `fruit` and `enter` do not match, `else:` is executed for `if`. If you correctly align `else:` with `for`, the code will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, this line
**print('this fruit doesn't exist')**
runs for each element that is not a match in the list. That's the problem.

```
x = ['apple','orange','banana','kiwi']

enter = str(input('enter your fruit: '))

def exists():
  print('this fruit exists')

enter = enter.lower()

fruitExist = False

for fruit in x:
   if fruit.lower() == enter:
     fruitExist = True
     break

if fruitExist :
    exists()
else:
   print("this fruit doesn't exist")
```